# Android sip registration failed with error "IN_PROGRESS"

Tags: android, sip

I am working on simple SIP-client Android app.

But when I try to register `sipProfile` on Server, I get `errorCode = -9` and `errorMessage= 0`.

Here is my activity:

```
public SipManager sipManager;
private SipProfile sipProfile;

// here is the data, I've just erased it
private String USERNAME = "";
private String AUTHUSERNAME = "";
private String DOMAIN = "";
private String PASSWORD = "";
private int PORT = 5060;

public SipAudioCall call = null;
public String sipAddress = null;

private Button btnRegister, btnCloseProfile;
private TextView tvStatus;
public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
    btnCloseProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCloseProfile);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(register);
    btnCloseProfile.setOnClickListener(closeProfile);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

}

View.OnClickListener closeProfile = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        closeLocalProfile();
    }
};
View.OnClickListener register = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        initializeManager();
    }
};

void initializeManager(){
    if(sipManager == null) {
        sipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    initializeLocalProfile();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initializeManager();
}

public void initializeLocalProfile(){
    if (sipManager == null){
        return;
    }

    if (sipProfile != null){
        closeLocalProfile();
    }

    try {
        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(USERNAME, DOMAIN);
        builder.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        builder.setAuthUserName(AUTHUSERNAME);
        sipProfile = builder.build();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("ru.tenet.apdu.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        sipManager.open(sipProfile, pi, null);

        sipManager.setRegistrationListener(sipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                updateStatus("Ready");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                updateStatus("Registration failed with error:\n" + SipErrorCode.toString(errorCode) +"\n"+errorMessage);
            }
        });

    }
    catch (SipException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        updateStatus("SipException");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        updateStatus("ParseException");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (call != null) {
        call.close();
    }

    closeLocalProfile();
    if (callReceiver != null) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
    }
}

public void closeLocalProfile() {
    if (sipManager == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        if (sipProfile != null) {
            sipManager.close(sipProfile.getUriString());
        }
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        Log.d("StatusWindow/onDestroy", "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
    }
}

void updateStatus(final String status){
    Log.d("mylog","status = " +status);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tvStatus.setText(status);
        }
    });
}

public void updateStatus(SipAudioCall call) {
    String useName = call.getPeerProfile().getDisplayName();
    if(useName == null) {
        useName = call.getPeerProfile().getUserName();
    }
    updateStatus(useName + "@" + call.getPeerProfile().getSipDomain());
}
```

And my Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

If I try with following code:

```
sipManager.open(sipProfile, pi, null);
sipManager.register(sipProfile, 20, new SipRegistrationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                updateStatus("Ready");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                updateStatus("Registration failed with error:\n" + SipErrorCode.toString(errorCode) +"\n"+errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

I get SipException:

```
android.net.sip.SipException: SipService.createSession() returns null
```

**FIXED**

It looks like one of the sip sessions has been frozen on device.
After physical reboot I got my registration

Comment: Related: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101938/sipaudiocall-without-registering-a-local-sipprofile), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174067/android-sipmanager-android-net-sip-sipexception-sipservice-createsession-ret) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077623/android-sipprofile-uri-udp-port-error).

Comment: @Sufian,
Thanks, I've watched these questions, but didn't find the solution there

Comment: It is highly recommended to do it now. Update your question and mention that you tried the solutions in these questions and also state what happened or not.

Answer (score 0):

In case this error you need close local profile and repeat create session

```
   manager.setRegistrationListener(me.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {
                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                     updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                     updateStatus("Ready");
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                                 String errorMessage) {
                    if(errorCode == SipErrorCode.IN_PROGRESS) {
                        closeLocalProfile();
                        try {
                            manager.open(me, pi, null);
                        } catch (SipException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

> After lot of searching and going through multiple stackoverflow answers and wasting 2 days on registration errors, here are the things that you should consider to get the registration done ! These worked for me. Reply to this answer if they work for you too :)

**Check for the following your code:**

1. First of all, check whether all required permissions are given or not
2. Use `open` method instead of register & `close` instead of unregister
3. Set your `SipRegisterationListener` after calling open method, pass `null` as a parameter in `open` method for listener and call `sipManager.setRegisterationListener(listener)` to set the listener.
4. Your domain must not include port number it should be simple server domain link ; For example `com.google.com`
5. First try running the app without setting the port number in `SipProfile.Builder` ; if that fails, add port manually using `builder.setPort(xxxx)`
6. Try changing the protocol. Currently only `UDP` & `TCP` are the options available as mentioned [in this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipProfile.Builder#setProtocol(java.lang.String))
7. Check that your profile uri built is of the format `sip:<username>@<domain>`. For example if the username is ***abcd*** and domain is ***com.google.com***, the `SipProfile` uri string should be `sip:abcd@com.google.com`

**Try the following things if your android code is correct :**

1. Check the username and password properly / try some other username and password. Before trying with other credentials, close the existing SipProfile until is is successfully closed.
2. Clear data of `Phone Service` system apps from your phone
3. Clear data of your developed SIP app also
4. Close any open / existing SIP accounts on the device from `Phone > Settings > Calling Accouts > Sip Accounts`;
5. Reboot your phone